# Dynamically load value from $_POST or $_GET the short way

Tags: php, forms, post, get

I'm writing a form-helper class in php, that should check if a value is submitted via the method, the form defined.

```
public function getValue($name) {
    $getFrom  = ($this->method == 'post') ? '_POST' : '_GET';
    return isset($$getFrom[$name]) ? $$getFrom[$name] : null;
}
```

$this->method is post or get, it's form-dependent.
This method looks fine for me, but php throws a "Illegal string offset" warning. What can I do without using an if-block.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know about `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: what is this `$$getFrom`

Comment: >php throws a "Illegal string offset" warning.
What line?

Comment: @̇̇̇ `$$getFrom` evaluates to `$_POST` or `$_GET`. @OP - use `$_REQUEST`

Comment: Variable variable syntax to access `$_GET` or `$_POST` doesn't work from within local scopes. They're only implicit aliases, and needed to be specifically invited.

Comment: @̇̇̇ it appears to be a variable variable.

Comment: php throws the warning on the line where getValue($name) is used... But the problem is, $this->method is 'post' or 'get' according to the form, that is defined by the coder and only this request should be used.

Comment: I believe the problem is that he didn't enclose $getFrom, so it is treating $getFrom as an array. He need to use ${$getFrom}[$name] to ensure it parses $getFrom first and then treats the result as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that the replies have been an attempt to help the user with a better approach, but they do not answer the question. Why is it throwing the error that he sees? I just tested this to ensure I was correct in my assumption.

When he uses $$getFrom[$name], PHP first parses "$getFrom[$name]". That is what is throwing the error. He obviously wants $getFrom to be parsed without including [$name]. So, he needs to use ${$getFrom}[$name].

Comment: Thank you for your fast and good reply. This solution works for me and answers my question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
public function getValue($name) {       
   return isset($_REQUEST[$name]) ? $_REQUEST[$name] : null;
}
```

Comment: why even use the `$getFrom` variable?

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn, Yeah.. that is not neccessary!! Thanks!